# Verifying an audio stream is actually played and heard

Tags: java, android, audio, pattern-recognition

I'm broadcasting an audio stream (predefined playlists not live) through an HTTP server. I'm wondering are there any cheap solutions (in terms of computational complexity) which I can confirm my stream is actually played and heard. This means a reasonable amount of audio output is broadcasted from device which resembles mostly that stream.

For a simple scenario: assume there is an Android device & app, which is responsible for connecting to the server and playing the stream. Same Android app will be used to capture microphone input and compare it with the stream. Testing environment is outdoor scene with low-to-moderate background noise.

I did some studying with FFT and audio analysis in the college but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel so I'm seeking reliable and cheap libraries for this matter (mainly Android but Java libraries are welcome too).

As a side note, I started out with getting volume levels from the device, but this turned out to be insufficient since user can just plug in a turned off speaker to the device.

---

You might think the amount of work required to accomplish such a feature might not be feasible. But keep in mind that this feature I'm working on is between the "content generator" and "broadcaster", NOT "broadcaster" vs. "listener". So all I'm trying to do is making sure the broadcaster is holding his end of the contract.

Comment: Well you can't prove it was heard-  even if it plays nobody may be in the room.  Hell even if there is someone you can't prove he's paying attention, or wearing headphones, or isn't deaf.  I question that you're solving the right problem.

Comment: I'd just check that the volume is not set to 0.  What you're talking about is an awful large amount of work that probably doesn't solve you're real problem-  if you want to know if the user was paying attention, ask him questions about the content instead.  You'll get better results.

Comment: Actually it IS my real problem. Individual listeners are not really my concern. I want to implement this system as a control mechanism to make sure the broadcasting user actually broadcasts given content..

Comment: Like I said-  check that the volume is nonzero.  The number of users you'll miss because hey decided to unplug a device speaker will be dwarfed by your false negatives due to a user wearing headphones or bluetooth earpieces.